# Password Prompt For Wifi Connections in Linux

Tags: linux, passwords, wireless-networking, opensuse

I have been using a few flavors of Linux for a while now.  But, I Still haven't figured out how to turn off the repetitive password prompt for Connecting to a Wifi networks.  Is there an automated way, similar to how Windows handles it?

Comment: To superuser with you *waves wand*

Comment: installing gnome-keyring might help.

Answer (score 0):

Wicd-gtk ? It depends which distribution you have, which network manager you have.
If the one you're using doesn't fit with you, just switch to another one. Wicd is great.